# Left Aligning Subscripts

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

[image]

When using displayed (in contrast to inline) equations LaTeX center-aligns subscripts:

```
\Pr\limits_{{r \leftarrow_R \{0,1\}^n}} [ ... ]
```

However, I like them to be left aligned. This can be done by using `\hspace`

```
\Pr\limits_{\hspace{1cm}{r \leftarrow_R \{0,1\}^n}}  [ ... ]
```

But this is not a good solution, since the parameter of `\hspace` must be specified manually. (It differs based on the font and the length of the subscript.)

What other option I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Prl}[1]{
  \mathop{\oalign{$\Pr$\hfill\cr
    $\begin{subarray}{l}#1\end{subarray}$\hfill\cr}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\Prl{r \leftarrow_R \{0,1\}^n}abc \\
\Prl{r \leftarrow_R \{0,1\}^n\\abc}abc
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

But I find this layout horrible, particularly in in-line formulas. :)

Comment: "this": the OP's desired layout, or the solution?

Comment: @Brent: The desired layout, of course. :)

Comment: +1, Good! But, can you make it work, even when the subscripts are stacked (using `subarray`)?

Comment: @Sadeq: now it uses `subarray`; you give `\Prl` the subscript with rows separated, as usual, by `\\`